# Is the word "ideator" acceptable in public communication; is there a better word?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I can't find "ideator" in traditional dictionaries, but I've found it on [urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ideator) and with an unfortunate definition on [Medical Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Ideator) (related to suicide).

**Urban Dictionary**

> Ideator A person who creates productive ideas, a conceptualist.A
>   person that processes and passes on their ideas and inventions to
>   others to help sell or publisize a commodity. A solutions person,
>   problem solver, think tank.

**Medical Dictionary**

> A person experiencing suicidal ideation

So, my question is twofold:

1. If I use this in public communication such as articles, white-papers, etc., does this word harm my credibility or the quality of my writing?
2. Is there a better word that means the same thing?

Here is an example of the word in-context in an article about leadership and the workforce:

> Marcus is an ideator, but, generally, current corporate structures and
>   cultures do not know what to do with an ideator; there's no processes
>   or expertise to identify, encourage, nurture or leverage ideators
>   within the workforce. Frustrated, ideators leave organizations to join
>   other organizations or to strike out on their own when most businesses
>   could greatly benefit from the presence of ideators within their
>   ranks...

Comment: 'Ideas man / woman' used to be quite common.

Comment: It is interesting that the OED does not have an entry for *suicidal ideation*, nor does it link *ideator* with this medical use. I recognise that it is in various medical dictionaries but am puzzled as to why this has not been picked up more generally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the strong negative connotations created by the specialized medical use, using *ideator* in a serious positive context is a tough decision. A person imagining suicide is actually a denotation of *[ideator](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/ideator)*  :

> A person experiencing suicidal ideation
>   *medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com*

On the other hand, that derivative is based on a broader definition of *[ideate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ideate)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT] chiefly Psychology
>   1.0 Form an idea of; imagine or conceive.
>
> 1.1 [NO OBJECT] Form ideas; think.
>   *ODO*

Consistent with the definition on [Urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ideator), Wiktionary offers a general definition of [ideator](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ideator):

> One who ideates; one who holds or generates an idea, or synthesizes a
>   concept.
>   *Wiktionary.com*

There is [significant evidence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ideator%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22ideator%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks) that *ideator* continues to be used in positive non-slang contexts. One example from pages 262-264 of *[Creative Leadership: Skills That Drive Change](https://books.google.com/books?id=lF-687006ckC&pg=PA264&dq=%22ideator%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=knYlVeq9E4e9sAXx04GQAg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22ideator%22&f=false)* by Gerard J. Puccio, Marie Mance and Mary C. Murdock:

> This indicates that, as the ***Ideator*** score goes up, so does an
>   individual's tendency to produce many original ideas. [discussion
>   omitted]...
>   Meanwhile, the ***Ideator*** scale showed a strong negative relationship
>   with Steadiness. This finding reveals that individuals with high
>   ***Ideator*** tendencies have a degree of comfort with change, seek variety,and are willing to challenge prevailing thought [discussion
>   omitted]...
>   For example, effective *ideation* may not only depend on
>   one's ability to think like an ***Ideator*** but also to experience
>   feeling like an ***ideator***.
>   ***Emphasis*** mine

Apparently, some creative people are convinced that the positive connotations of *ideate*, overcome the negative connotations of the medical usage.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I'm assuming that you don't have any better alternatives to suggest, is that correct?

Comment: You are welcome, @mawcsco. To recommend an alternative, I would need a clear sense of how you intend to use the word. The larger context of a sentence impacts word selection.

Comment: I agree with @ScotM that context would be necessary to suggest an alternative. "Ideator" is a very seldom used word, though perhaps in some professional services it may be common. I would not know what you were talking about if you used it in a sentence or spoke it to me. Context would lead me to guess at the meaning.

Comment: I've added context to my original question.

Answer (score 5):

> Marcus is an **innovator**, but, generally, current corporate
>   structures and cultures do not know what to do with an **innovator**;
>   there's no processes or expertise to identify, encourage, nurture or
>   leverage **innovators** within the workforce. Frustrated,
>   **innovators** leave organizations to join other organizations or to strike out on their own when most businesses could greatly benefit
>   from the presence of **innovators** within their ranks...

*[innovator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/innovator)*:

> noun
>
> A person who ***introduces*** new methods, ideas, or products:
>   *ODO **Emphasis** mine*

An article from Forbes Magazine, by John Hall, articulates why many corporate cultures discourage *ideators* and their innovative ideas:

> **10 Barriers to Employee Innovation**
>
> 1. Closed-Mindedness...
> 2. Traditions...
> 3. Jealousy...
> 4. Money...
> 5. Generational Differences/Age...
> 6. Communication...
> 7. Size...
> 8. Education...
> 9. Thought Leadership...
> 10. Resources...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am decidedly avoiding the word "innovator" in my current project. I left that information out of my question because I wondered if anyone would recommend this word. You've validated my hypothesis, so thanks again.

Comment: Sometimes it's wise to **clothe** strengths others define as weaknesses in the "weakness" they define as strength, @mawcsco. Marcus may overcome the obstacles and find a way to bring innovation to his new job anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We used the word, 'ideator' almost 30 years ago in advertising business for the creators such as copy writers, art directors and storyboard writers who always come up with fresh and selling idea and ad concept, though I'm not very sure if it still applies today or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting just to say that I like **originator** as well.

> originator - someone who creates new things or ideas

The originator of something such as an idea or scheme is the person who first thought of it or began it. [[definition]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/originator) [definition 2](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/originator)

*In this way he became the **originator** of that genetic or historical method which has since been applied to all human ideas and institutions.*