# What is the name/title for someone who generates ideas?

Tags: names, titles, epithet-requests

what is the name/title for someone who generates ideas?

Here idea refers to things like:

- Doing a project together
- Something can be done
- Something is possible
- Someone can try something
- Something can be done in *this* way / *that* way
- Something can be arranged

The person in reference can be someone --

- who is generating ideas professionally
- who is doing a community service
- who is helping / trying to help others by the ideas
- who is a leader giving the ideas to followers

Thanks in advance for your kind opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [***inventor***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inventor)
- [***innovator***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/innovator)
- [***visionary***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/visionary)
- [***thought leader***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_leader)

Answer (score 3):

A common term for a *man* who generates ideas is

> **ideas man**  *n.* (also **idea man**)  [compare French *homme d'idée* intellectual (1832), *homme à idées* creative, inventive, or ingenious man (1935)] a creative, inventive, or ingenious man, **a man who comes up with ideas**.

["idea, n.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90954?rskey=IvrZCr&result=8&isAdvanced=false (accessed March 22, 2016). Final bold emphasis mine.]

In some contexts 'idea man' will be considered unacceptably chauvinistic or impolitic. For general and specific contexts where the reference may be to women, preferable terms include 'idea person', 'idea people', 'idea woman', etc. The term does not, to my knowledge, suffer any loss of recognition or change of meaning when implemented in gender-neutral terminology, or applied to a woman or women specifically.

Answer (score -2):

How about this word....  Ideator

Comment: Discussed here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238235/using-the-word-ideator